# Getting a 404 error when calling a Model Function in owl JavaScript file in Odoo 16, how can I fix this?

Tags: odoo-16

I am new to Odoo and I am using odoo16 version. I want to call Model Function in owl JavaScript file, but it shows 404 error and URL is made `http://localhost:8069/[object%20Object]` like this.

I am using RPC service `this.rpc = useService("rpc")`

```
await this.rpc({
         model: 'hr.kpi.emp.desig',
         method: 'get_desig_emp',
         args: []
    }).then(function (data) {
         console.log(data);
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I am trying to call Model function into JavaScript file. I created a component in static/src/components/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

The problem is we use the wrong service on odoo version 16. Please use the "orm" service, not "rpc"

In your case:

`this.orm = useService("orm");`

`//call(model, method, args, kwargs)`

`await result = this.orm.call(''hr.kpi.emp.desig', 'get_desig_emp', [], {})`

Comment: Thanks. Now I am using ORM service rather than RPC